# How to decompress using Inflater in Java?

Tags: java, compression, inflate, deflate

I am very new to Java.

I have some codes to compress like below:

```
public void compress(OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(1);
    DeflaterOutputStream zOut = new DeflaterOutputStream(out, deflater, 1024);
    DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(zOut);

    stream.writeShort(200);
    stream.write("test".getBytes("utf-8"));

    zOut.close();
    deflater.end();
}
```

And I am using that function as below:

```
    compress c = new compress();
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Temp\\file.bin");
    OutputStream out = fis;
    c.compress(out);
    fis.close();
```

Now, I need to decompress my file.bin file.

I have looked up several samples, but none of them shows me about the compression level.

The constructor of Deflater has 1 argument which is compression level.

Don't I have to mention that when decompressing it?

Anyway, please show me the proper way to decompress this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I think you're running a little to low in the API, maybe you should consider the `ZipInput/OutputStream` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea how to do it using InflaterInputStream:

```
public static void decompress(File compressed, File raw)
        throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in =
            new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(compressed));
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(raw);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        int len;
        while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't have to worry about the compression level when decompressing?

Comment: No, You Do not need to worry.

Comment: Your Welcome @JoshuaSon . Have fun coding :)